# Regular Expression to detect Company Tickers using JAVA

Tags: regex

I am attempting to filter out company tickers from possible list of tickers.

Following code is what I got so far, I need to make the RegExp sophisticated enough that only certain pattern is passed.  See example code below for more specific details.

```
Pattern tickerPattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z:\\.0-9]+$");

String[] tickerStrArr={
                    "JELK90#$",  // NOT A TICKER
                    "1",         // NOT A TICKER
                    "0",         // NOT A TICKER
                    "R",         // NOT A TICKER
                    "25.36",     // NOT A TICKER
                    "1.0",       // NOT A TICKER
                    "GOOG",      // Ticker
                    "NYSE:C",    // Ticker (with exchange code NYSE)
                    "GOOG.BY",   // Ticker (with exchange code BY)
                    "$90",       // NOT A TICKER
                    "98774",     // Ticker (because more than 4 digit long)
                    "789.BY"     // Ticker (because ends with .[A-Z]{2,2})
                   };

for(String tickerStr: tickerStrArr)
{
    Matcher matcher =tickerPattern.matcher(tickerStr);

    if(matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println("It's a ticker=>"+matcher.group());
    }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
It's a ticker=>GOOG
It's a ticker=>NYSE:C
It's a ticker=>GOOG.BY
It's a ticker=>98774
It's a ticker=>789.BY
```

Can you formulate required RegExp which will get the above expected output?

Here are rules for my own filtering (not necessarily applicable to everyone)

1. Only Character or Numbers could be part of ticker, no special char or currency symbol.
2. Sometimes tickers are mentioned along with their exchange code as prefix
   For example => NYSE:C
   Or there could be **two character** exchange code as suffix
   For Example => C.BY
3. If it is all digit then it should be more than 4 digits. (this is to rule out millions of False positives)
4. But, if digits are mentioned along with exchange code then ticker could be less than 4 digits. Because, then we have high confidence.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: In case you wanted to learn how to learn: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18132398/278976

Comment: @Homer6 Thanks for the link, I posted the question thinking this might be a good problem to share with everyone. Otherwise, after spending some time, I can figure this out on my own. Also, RegexBuddy doesn't work on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Are you sure that [R](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/R) isn't a ticker symbol? I believe that every single-letter ticker symbol is taken as these are seen as quite prestigious.

Comment: @Code-Guru Indeed. Stock tickers have different rules across different exchanges, and different sets of valid characters. Generating a regex that covered them all would be very, very challenging.

Comment: Imagine you find that regex, what does it bring you? Even a string that matches your regex could be a non-existing ticker ==> the best way is not a regex, but querying a data source and checking if the ticker exists.

Comment: Also "*If it is all digit then it should be more than 4 digits. (this is to rule out millions of False positives)*" => no it will only rule out 999 possible false positive. And note that 735 is a valid ticker for example, in hong kong...

Comment: @Code-Guru, I added the rule which suits my data set. I gave hypothetical example to minimize the scope of problem.

Comment: @assylias, I meant million FP in my own data-set. I don't care about world at this time. Because my data set has millions of 1-3 digit long char which are not actually tickers.

Comment: I am realizing my mistake, I should have not mentioned the word "ticker", people started to assume a lot, instead of solving the straight-forward filtering where pattern is clearly defined. :)

Comment: @Code-Guru, before you nitpick on my hypothetical data, I must tell you GOOG.BY also not a valid ticker exchange combination. Since this filtering is tricky and might involve some sophisticated RegEX knowledge that is why I posted here.

Comment: @Watt My apologies for nitpicking your example. I should have started by asking you to explain the rules for deciding what a ticker symbol is.

Comment: @Code-Guru, not a problem, thanks for your comment; that allows me not be discouraged in the future in thinking of sharing such tricky problem with everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following regex will match the following.

- Start of the String
- **PreXChangeCode**: optionally match a-z, 2 to 4 times, except if there is a `.` somewhere later.  This is to detect an invalid symbol with multiple exchange symbols
- **Stock**: a-z 1 to 4 times OR digit 1-3 times followed by a period OR a digit 4 or more times
- **PostXChangeCode**: Optionally match a `.` follow by a-z exactly 2 times.
- End of String

### Regex

```
 ^
 (?<PreXChangeCode>[a-z]{2,4}:(?![a-z\d]+\.))?
 (?<Stock>[a-z]{1,4}|\d{1,3}(?=\.)|\d{4,})
 (?<PostXChangeCode>\.[a-z]{2})?
 $
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/lq5h3r)

I tested it out with [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/lq5h3r) and it correctly matches your test data with the exception for `R`. I included one character stock names since those are valid (R is Ryder Systems).

Comment: +1 Thanks, I knew this is possible to get through RegEx. BTW, I deliberately excluded R or any single word ticker because in my data-set there are thousands R or other single world char in sentences where they are not actually mean as ticker (for instance R=registered). I was ok with not getting single word tickers, because I have a separate look-up process to filter out all single word tickers.

Comment: if this regex is to be used for more than just the OP's tickers you have to take into account some stocks like "BRK-B" which have the "-" symbol

Comment: You could add after the stock group `(?<alt>-[a-z])?`

Comment: Ticker symbols are always uppercase. It helps with accuracy.

Comment: does this support stock symbols such as GOOGL ?

Comment: @Dev18 if you changed 4 to 5 in the first quantifier in the second capture group then it should work.