# Kotlin's matchEntire regex function does not catch what its Java equivalent would

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I'm trying to validate that an input string is a valid stock ticker symbol in an Android app. Neither the regex, nor the test cases that I am using is original: they are validated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647885/regular-expression-to-detect-company-tickers-using-java).

What is original, is my adaptation of the original Java code to Kotlin:

```
fun String.isValidTickerSymbol(): Boolean {
    val validTickerFormat = Regex("/^(([a-z]{2,4}):(?![a-z\\d]+\\.))?([a-z]{1,4}|\\d{1,3}(?=\\.)|\\d{4,})(\\.([a-z]{2}))?$/i")
    val results = validTickerFormat.matchEntire(this)?.groupValues

    return (results != null)
}
```

When I run my JUnit test suite on it (the assertions syntax here follows [Kluent](https://github.com/MarkusAmshove/Kluent)); it fails at "GOOG", telling me that string is not valid, when it should be.

```
"JELK90#$".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual false
"1".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual false
"0".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual false
"R".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual false
"25.36".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual false
"1.0".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual false
"GOOG".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual true
"NYSE:C".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual true //with exchange code NYSE
"GOOG.BY".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual true //with exchange code BY
"$90".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual false
"98774".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual true //because more than 4 digit long
"789.BY".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual true //because ends with .[A-Z]{2,2}
```

Is my understanding of the `kotlin.text.Regex` class wrong? Is there something odd happening with the escape characters in the regular expression itself?

Comment: By default, regexes in Kotlin created this way are not case-insensitive. I'm not sure that Java regexes support the `/.../i` syntax for indicating case-insensitivity?

Comment: `"goog".isValidTickerSymbol() shouldEqual true` doesn't pass either; so it's more than a case sensitivity issue, if it's that

Comment: Passing `setOf(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)` to the second parameter of the `Regex` constructor made no difference in test outcome (even while also removing the `i` at the end of the regexp)

Comment: I wrote an equivalent function using `java.util.regex` instead of `kotlin.text.Regex` and it has the same problems. So the problem may not be Kotlin-specific; although online regex testers do validate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with the following Kotlin code (note I removed the delimiters from the regexp):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val regex =
        Regex("^(([a-z]{2,4}):(?![a-z\\d]+\\.))?([a-z]{1,4}|\\d{1,3}(?=\\.)|\\d{4,})(\\.([a-z]{2}))?$",
              RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
    listOf("JELK90#$",
           "1",
           "0",
           "R",
           "25.36",
           "1.0",
           "GOOG",
           "NYSE:C",
           "GOOG.BY",
           "$90",
           "98774",
           "789.BY").forEach {
        val results = regex.matchEntire(it)?.groupValues
        println(results)
    }
}
```

And the result is the following:

```
null
null
null
[R, , , R, , ]
null
null
[GOOG, , , GOOG, , ]
[NYSE:C, NYSE:, NYSE, C, , ]
[GOOG.BY, , , GOOG, .BY, BY]
null
[98774, , , 98774, , ]
[789.BY, , , 789, .BY, BY]
```

So, it matches exactly what you expect plus "R", which is matched by `[a-z]{1,4}` present in the 3rd capturing group

Comment: Thanks, removing the delimiters (and changing my expectation for what "R" should return) did the trick.